# Updating java version 7 to version 8 in Android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I've downloaded java version 8 but i am not able to run it in windows 10. when ever i try to run it as administrator and then click yes on the pop up box, nothing happens, so I am not able to run it in android studio also. any help?

[image: Android studio screenshot]

Comment: What popup box? The Java 8 installer?

Comment: no , that "Do you want this app to make changes to your device?" and when i click on "yes" button nothing happens.

Comment: The Windows UAC popup? Sounds like a permissions issue. How did you get Java 7 installed? You could try this site  https://ninite.com/jdk/

Comment: tried form the website and install failed. And the thing is that i am able to install java 8 from oracle in pc but i am not able to run it. i mean the version always remains 7 even after the updation

Comment: Wait... You just said you are able to install? So it didn't fail? If you want to switch from 7 to 8, you have to modify your system PATH environment variables and/or you need to update the SDK settings of the IDE. It's not as simple as running an installer

Comment: The thing is i was able to install it but i am not able to run it. when ever i try to run the application a permission pop up appears asking "do you want this app to make changes to to your device?"  and when i click on yes, nothing happens, even when i change the path ,  and check whether the java version has been updated by going to command prompt the version is always 7.                                                             like when we install java version 7 the setup appears and by following instructions we are able to install 7, no such thing happens when i install java version 8.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include relevant screenshots of the problem?

Comment: As in screen shots when i try to install java version 7 the setup apears .. whereas when i try to install version 8 no setup, nothing happens. just the progress bar appears and then it is gone